# My computer fails to start virtual machine in Android Staudio and Genymotion

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

My virtual machine can boot up to this point, I can't open it up.
I fixed the error following the instructions on google but it didn't work. Everyone please help me fix this
Thanks!

[image]
[image]